# AM Charts - Line chart displaying in correct data

Tags: amcharts

I’m using AM charts to plot amounts per year over a number of years. I have created a code pen to show you my issue:

https://codepen.io/conormdowney/pen/QzamJb

My code to draw the chart:

```
var dataProvider = [
{year: "2017", value: 50},
{year: "2018", value: 123},
{year: "2019", value: 150},
{year: "2020", value: 291}
];

var _chart = am4core.create('chartDiv', am4charts.XYChart);
_chart.paddingRight = 20;

_chart.data = dataProvider;

var dateAxis = _chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0.5;
dateAxis.baseInterval = 
  {
  count: 1,
  timeUnit: "year"
}

var valueAxis = _chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
// Create series
var series = _chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "year";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.connect = false;
series.tensionX = 0.8;
series.fillOpacity = 0.2;
series.tooltipText = "[bold]{valueY}[/]";

var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
bullet.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
bullet.strokeWidth = 3;

var range = valueAxis.createSeriesRange(series);
range.value = 0;
range.endValue = 100;
range.contents.stroke = _chart.colors.getIndex(2);
range.contents.fill = range.contents.stroke;
range.contents.fillOpacity = 0.2;

var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
scrollbarX.series.push(series);
_chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
_chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

I have data from the year 2017 to 2020. When plotted it shows from 2016 to 2019, until you hover over the data in which case it highlights the data from the year after you are hovered. Can you tell me why this happens and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String-based dates need a corresponding `inputDateFormat` set in the chart's `dateFormatter` object to ensure that it is parsed consistently across all browsers (note that in Chrome the years are showing up correctly; I'm assuming you're using Firefox where you see 2016). Simply set the `inputDateFormat` to `"yyyy"` and you're all set.

```
_chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy";
```

You can find more information on date formats [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/) and an updated codepen [here](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/3c16578e371eeb05c6bf457446c34912).

Comment: Also, I am using Chrome but it still shows up as 2016 if I remove that line

Comment: Weird. It doesn't do that for me and I'm using the latest vesrion of Chrome. In any case, I'm glad it fixed the problem.